# Creating new users in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How to add new users for Tortoise SVN. I am using Windows server 2000.

Comment: It does not depend on TortoiseSVN, it depends on the server. Which server do you use?

Comment: No, which type of SVN-server do you use? A filesystem repository created by TortoiseSVN or the svnserve service (supplies svn-protocol) or an Apache HTTPD with the subversion plugin or Collabnet SVN server or VisualSVN server or....?

Comment: I don't know that. As omermuhammed said, ask the one who installed it. Could be buildin-users, could be active directory users or something else.

Answer (score -1):

New users are added on SVN server, your SVN admin should do that and provide authentication mechanism details (svn+ssh etc) to you, so that you can use Tortoise SVN to access the repository. Think of Tortoise as a front end to SVN repo, used to access your code.